# How to create an stl-like iterator which calls member functions

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to provide for my API some iterators which automatically call the desired member functions to directly iterate over the returned values. More precisely consider the following struct and main function as MVE:

```cpp
struct Shape
{
  double getArea()
  {
  return ....//calculate area;
  }

  double getVolume()
  {
  return ....//calculate volume;
  }

  std:pair<double,double> getVolumeAndArea()
  {
  return std:make_pair...;
  }

// some data members
}
```

Now i have a vector of shapes and i want to use it in the following way:

```cpp
int main(){

std:vector<Shape> shapes;
//fill shapes

for(const auto area : area(shapes))
  // do something with area


for(const auto volume : volume(shapes))
  // do something with volume


for(const auto [volume, area] : volumeAndArea(shapes))
  // do something with volume and area
}
```

Obviously, i can just iterate over shapes and write it directly in the code or write some `std:for_each` where inside the provided lamba the calls happen.

Nevertheless, i think the approach i have in mind is less verbose for a potential user.

Therefore, my question is how can this be solved with minimal boilerplate. Should i use some `boost` iterator or inherit from some `std::iterator` as return value of these free functions? I hope that there is an easy way which i have overseen. Since the mentioned options seem quite verbose. It would also be nice to have this rather generic. Since it would be nice to use it for several classes without repeating the iterator boilerplate.

Furthermore, i'm not restricted to an old c++ version, therefore, a nice c++20 solution is also welcome.

Therefore, can someone point me to a good example or a best-practice recommendation  how to do this in a modern way? I'm confident to workout details on my own, since i don't want to ask for a finished solution.

Comment: Take a look at ranges-v3 or C++20's range library.  They support using a pointer to member and you should be able to do the same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for your answer! To clarify your answer for me since you mentioned a "pointer to member": I have in mind that it iterates over the return values of the member function and not member variables since the calculations can be complicated and are not stored in a member vsriable. Did your answer also include this use case? This is not pretty clear to me since maybe me question was also not absolutely clear in this regard.

Comment: See cigen's answer below.  It will work with a pointer to a member variable or member function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20, the ranges versions of algorithms can take projections on members, which pretty much gets you the ease of use you want, with slightly different syntax

```
std::ranges::for_each(shapes, [](const auto & area) {
    // do something with area
}, &Shape::getArea);
// ^_____________^ projection on member
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rbh5WMrEW)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible implementation that uses iterators instead of any ranges (specifically for the area case):

```
class area {
private:
    class iterator {
    public:
        // needed so that it acts like a std::iterator
        using difference_type = int;
        using value_type = double;
        using reference = double;
        using pointer = std::add_pointer<value_type>;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

        double operator*() const {
            // compute the area when accessing the value of the iterator
            return shapes_[index_].getArea();
        }

        iterator &operator++() {
            index_++;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) const { return index_ == rhs.index_; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
        bool operator<(const iterator &rhs) const { return index_ < rhs.index_; }

        iterator(size_t index, const std::vector<Shape>& shapes) : index_(index), shapes_(shapes) {}

    private:
        size_t index_;
        const std::vector<Shape>& shapes_;
    };

public:
    area(const std::vector<Shape>& shapes) : shapes_(shapes) {}
    iterator begin() const { return iterator{0, shapes_}; }
    iterator end() const{ return iterator{shapes_.size(), shapes_}; }

private:
    const std::vector<Shape>& shapes_;
};

...

int main() {
    std::vector<Shape> shapes;
    for (const double area : area(shapes)) {

    }
}
```

Ranges look a lot easier!

For what it's worth, you could probably extract out the `iterator` class here and reuse it for all of the different functions (like passing it a `std::function` that is called on each of the shapes).

Comment: Thanks this is also a nice. In contrast to ranges it also has my desired syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out with the helpful hints given above. Thanks to
[cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842556/12484740), [mattlangford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842605/12484740) and [mooning duck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67842385/how-to-create-an-stl-like-iterator-which-calls-member-functions#comment119914353_67842385).

Using `std::ranges::transform_view` and projections gives the nice and expressive option to write the following

```cpp
using std::ranges::transform_view;
for(const auto area : transform_view(shapes, &Shape::getArea ))
        std::cout << area << "\n";
```

See also https://godbolt.org/z/3xqn5bdWE.

To also provide an API-like solution one can wrap that thing into:

```cpp
auto area(std::vector<Shape>& shapes)
{
    using std::ranges::transform_view;
    return transform_view(shapes, &Shape::getArea);
}
```

which can then be used as

```cpp
for(const auto area :  area(shapes))
   //do something with area
```

since the original transform_view version is also very expressive i think the area(...) solution is more compilcated to understand.

See https://godbolt.org/z/Gff8K9cr8.